# Looking for a JSF/RichFaces control to popup an input field

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

I need a text box like control.

When clicked on it pops up a small window or area where the user can see his previous text and update/edit his text.

I have a data table and what I'm trying to do is allow the user to edit the description,
but the description area is small so we won't fit everything.

So on click I'm trying to use a tool that pop up a small text window on the page that allows the user to add/update/delete

Any idea? Is there a such tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`<rich:modalPanel>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf) containing a `<h:inputText>` with its value bound to the text the user needs to edit/update.

When facing a similar requirement, I used the [`RichFaces.showModalPanel`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html) JS function on the `oncomplete` event of an `:

```
<a4j:commandButton actionListener="..."
    oncomplete="RichFaces.showModalPanel('myPopupPanel', {width: 500, top: 200});" />
```

Comment: hmmm interesting. I shall take a look at this definitely!

Comment: doesn't seem like we need an actionListener do we?

Comment: I used an actionListener to set some bean properties I needed to initialize before showing the popup.

Comment: Any way to do in just plain JSF (no RichFaces), or am I looking at a page flip for that?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I haven't figured out a way to do it in plain JSF, but BalusC might be able to help you with that